# Screen capture program that would have the option of capturing a predefined fixed region in Linux [Redhat/Centos]?

Tags: linux, screenshot, centos-7

I am trying to find a screen capture utility that could offer the above option in Centos 7.

In the old days of Windows, I used to have a small utility called MWSnap that was perfect for this task. These days PickPick also offers such option.
However, I have searched high and low and cannot find something for Linux.
Do you know of any? If so, I would be grateful to hear about it. 
Thanks.

[Edited to make the question a bit more clearer:] I am aware of utilities that can capture a window, a screen, or an area on the screen of your choice. No problem there. What I am searching for is the capability of capturing a 'fixed  region.'
A fixed region capture is pre-defined and you just place the region on the screen to capture what you want without further editing.
Some description is given here for Microsoft Windows' users:

https://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-screen-capture-a-fixed-region-instead-of-a-regular-print-screen-on-Windows-00054

Whilst I am familiar with such utilities in the Windows environment, I am trying to find out an alternative for Linux, and not any distro, but RedHat-based ones such as CentOS, etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Builtin shortcuts

- Capture the whole screen: <kbd>Print</kbd>
- Capture the current Window: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>
- Select and capture an area <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>

---

The shotcuts may depend on your desktop environment. The shortcuts above are working with:

- [Unity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)
- [Gnome-shell](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en)
- ...

Comment: please leave a comment if you have different shortcuts on your DE and what they are so I can improve the answer with this information.

Comment: Thank you for the time taken, but not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Kazam

can capture both Videos and Screenshots from ...

- area
- window
- fullscreen

[image: Kazam Area select]

Comment: Thank you for the time taken, but not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

xv does that pretty well for me, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xv_(software) 
It's pre-installed on slackware linux, and I imagine easily installable on your distribution of choice.
Its official website is http://www.trilon.com/xv/ where there's apparently a specific redhat rpm

P.S. And here's an xv image capture of the rectangular area in my browser window containing your question...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the time taken. I have now installe the XV, but cannot find 'Fixed Region' capability in it. Also, the script is soooooooooo old and not updated in years.
There are better applications/utilities out there. For example, you can use Shutter, or if so inclined to get your teeth into it, even GIMP offers capturing. But not a fixed region.  
Thanks again.

Comment: @Adrian Okay, sorry. I thought that by "fixed region" you meant an arbitrary rectangular region of the screen, that might contain pieces of several different windows (or just the more usual one window). And xv's "grab" does do that, http://www.trilon.com/xv/manual/xv-3.10a/control-window-5.html However, I now understand you to mean an arbitrary rectangular region specified by entering its coordinate boundaries, which xv can't do. As for its age, yeah, but it's very lightweight (everything is compared to the gimp:), and continues to do the things that it does do remarkably well, despite its age